# TypeError: Object has no method 'split' Error in spliting results[0].geometry.location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Error in splitting `results[0].geometry.location`. I am trying to split this

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
codeAddress();

function codeAddress() {
    var address = "Karachi, Pakistan";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var variable = results[0].geometry.location;
           // this will return latitutde and longitutde, I want to split this
           // because it is in a format like (54.8773,99.8038994749)
           var next = variable.split(",");
           // this giving an error "TypeError: Object has no method 'split'"
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`location` property](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderGeometry) is a [LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) instance, not an array. Use the `lat()` and `lng()` methods to extract the coordinates:

```
var variable = results[0].geometry.location;
var next     = [ variable.lat(), variable.lng() ];
```